# Assigned value from table saved as null first time only in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am assigning the values to the variables from the table, First time value saved as 'null', I will get values if i execute the same script again . I could not able to reproduce null the issue immediately

```
DECLARE @l_a int,
        @l_b int,
        @l_c nvarchar(20),
        @l_d nvarchar(20)

SELECT
  @l_c = '',
  @l_d = ''

SELECT
  @l_a = a,
  @l_b = b,
  @l_c = c,
  @l_d = d
FROM table_name --it returns 1 row only


UPDATE it
SET it.a = a,
    it.c = ISNULL(NULLIF(@l_c, ''), it.c),
    it.d = ISNULL(NULLIF(@l_d, ''), it.d)
FROM table_name2 it
```

Comment: How many records you are have in `table_name` table. I suspect you have more than one record

Comment: ISNULL(NULLIF(c, ''), it.c) are not necessary its an annulation!

Comment: prdp, table_name is having one record only, if it have more than 1 value, i could get result instead of null

Comment: it.c = ISNULL(NULLIF(@l_d, ''), it.d) is an error, i suppose you want write  it.d = ISNULL(NULLIF(@l_d, ''), it.d)

Comment: yest,please check now

Comment: my code is not what you want?

Comment: I must use the variable,can you assist why very first time saved as null

Comment: in between select & update statement, i have some other code to process, I have removed it here

Answer (score 0):

you want say no? :

```
UPDATE it
SET it.a = @l_a,
it.c = ISNULL(NULLIF(@l_c, ''), it.c),
it.d = ISNULL(NULLIF(@l_d, ''), it.d)
FROM table_name2 it
```

or you can replace all your code without variables like this :

```
UPDATE it2
SET it2.a = it1.a,
it2.c = ISNULL(NULLIF(it1.c, ''), it2.c),
it2.d = ISNULL(NULLIF(it1.d, ''), it2.d)
FROM table_name2 it2 cross join table_name it1
```

Comment: c & d contains the value, but when i execute the select statement for table_name2, it is showing as null. After i run the save query again then i get proper value

Comment: if declared variable has null value,then i update same value of the column

Comment: i have modified my code, but i suppose you have an error you set 2x it.c